# Custom syntax coloring in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting

I never though I'd need this in such language as Python, but I actually really do after finding out that I can pass some type info and create dataclasses.

The point is that I use VSCode with Andromeda theme which i really like, and use it for some time right now, however - the theme doesn't color out the types.

I'd really like types to be styled as bold italic in some sea-alike colour, but I can't really find a straight way to do it.
I'm not sure if it's possible to style out like this not only the basic types but also lib classes (numpy.ndarray for example).

[image: This is how it looks right now]

Comment: find the TextMate scope of the types and then customize the scope color, search SO for examples

Comment: I have managed to do what i wished to accomplish in under 30 minutes. Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer i injected into my "settings.json" for those who would face the same problem in the future:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Andromeda Italic]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "support.type.python",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#00ceb2",
                    "fontStyle": "italic bold"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```